# Does canvas.getContext("2d") return the same instance every time?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'd like to know if `canvas.getContext("2d")` is guaranteed to return the same instance of the context every time it's called.

The reason I want to know is because I'm trying to follow [the advice in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525107/html5-canvas-image-scaling-issue) so that my scaled canvases don't look blurry.  But I create many canvases in my game so I'd like to make a `createCanvas` function that can be used by all.  I want it to look something like this:

```
function createCanvas(x, y) {
  canvas = $("<canvas width='" + x + "' height='" + y + "'></canvas>")[0];
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;  //modify the context
  return canvas;  //return the canvas, not the ctx
}
```

If `canvas.getContext("2d")` returns a new instance every time, this won't have any effect.  I need to return the canvas because other code uses that.

Is there a better solution to this problem?  If so, I'll accept that and rename my title.

---

**EDIT:** After I asked I noticed [this article](http://kodogames.com/optimising-html5-canvas-games/) says you can get the canvas from the context by doing `ctx.canvas`.  Pretty good tip.

Comment: Note that `canvas` in your code return a jquery object not a DOM elem. For performance you might as well create the canvas element natively.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For any one canvas element, `canvas.getContext("2d")` always returns the one-and-only context for that one canvas element.

Source: [HTML 5.2 §4.2 Scripting](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-scripting.html#2d)

> Return the same object as was return the last time the method was invoked with this same first argument.

If you create a new canvas element with `document.createElement("canvas")` (or jquery equivalent) then getContext on that new canvas will return a unique context for that new canvas.

Comment: A source validating this answer: *Return the same object as was return the last time the method was invoked with this same argument.* [Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#dom-canvas-getcontext)